# Adobe Flash CS6 gives me an error when importing image sequence to timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, import, action

It will import the first 10 images but anything after that just won't work and the workspace turns completely blank and I need to restart Flash CS6.

How ever if I import the images in a new project, nothing wrong happens. I tried to export it as a swf and import that to the original swf file but it didn't work. It just imported the images that I was able to import earlier.

Is there any solution with AS3 where I can load another swf and close the current one opened? Or any other solution to importing the images.

Thanks!

Comment: So I found out how to load a swf file, but how would I unload it/get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

> but anything after that just won't work and the workspace turns completely blank and I need to restart Flash CS6

I assume you export big images, so you have out of memory in your development environment.
Do you need Image Gallery? It isn't hard to create [simple image gallery](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3gridgallery/), and of course you don't need to import images to the library and publish with application.

> So I found out how to load a swf file, but how would I unload it/get rid of it?

If you decided to wrap your images in swf. By referencing `Loader` that you have used for loading swf, you could unload child SWF — [Loader.unloadAndStop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop%28%29)

Comment: It's not an image gallery, it's a sequence of images of a 3D animation. The animation plays, then when the animation is done, you hover the mouse over a part that's part of the animation and it tells you what that part is. The reasons why I'm doing this on flash is because I want it to be interactive, I need the background to be transparent, and that it can be viewed within the browser on a site without needing additional software.


Problem is though, I can only have a max of 3 scenes until Flash will get all weird and wont import any more images to the project. But I need to have 6 scenes.